# How to apply accordion in jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I have a problem with creating accordions in my page where I'm using blogger API. I need to apply accordion format to a list of Blogger posts at http://www.winworldgk.tk , which are fetched using Blogger API. The problem is- I'm able to display all post contents and titles but are of general style not the required accordion style. Could any one there be help. The code is as bellow...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Make a JSONP request for the Posts on the Blogger Buzz blog
        $.ajax({
          url:"https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/578441859855451483/posts?labels=EnglishTest&maxResults=5&key=mykey",
    dataType: "jsonp",success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var items = []; 

            // Construct a chunk of HTML for each post
            // containing the Post title, content, and a 
            // link to the post author.
            $.each(data.items, function(index, value) {     
    $('<h3><a href="#">'+value.title+'</a></h3><div>'+value.content+'</div>').appendTo("#accId");
    }


    });$("#accId").addClass("accordion");
    }


    });
    });




<html>
<body>
<div id="accId"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do u have `$("#accId").addClass("accordion");` inside the ajax call??